# Parse Server - Uploading files using AppId vs FileKey for directory name

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

This question is in regarding to Parse Server deployment done on Heroku/Localhost Vs. Parse.com behavior:

If I upload files to Parse.com I get a URL as:

```
http://files.parsetfss.com/<fileKey>/<unique-id>-<provided-filename>
```

But, when I use the deployment on Heroku or Localhost, I get a URL as:

```
http://localhost:1337/<appId>/<unique-id>-<provided-filename>
```

I have provided a fileKey in my index.js of my parse server, yet it doesn't use it when creating the URL but instead uses the AppId for the directory in the URL.

Is there a setting so I can hide the appId and simply use the fileKey?

Thank you.